# List of squareful, cubeful, etc. numbers

Tags: list-manipulation

The following works:

```
list = {6, 7, 8, 9};
FreeQ2[n_Integer] := FreeQ[Last@Transpose@FactorInteger[n], _?(# >= 2 &)]
FreeQ3[n_Integer] := FreeQ[Last@Transpose@FactorInteger[n], _?(# >= 3 &)]
FreeQ4[n_Integer] := FreeQ[Last@Transpose@FactorInteger[n], _?(# >= 4 &)]
a = FreeQ2 /@ list /. {True -> 1, False -> 0};
b = FreeQ3 /@ list /. {True -> 2, False -> 0};
c = FreeQ4 /@ list /. {True -> 3, False -> 0};
Transpose[{a, b, c}] /. {{1, 2, 3} -> 1, {0, 2, 3} -> 2, {0, 0, 3} -> 3}
```

but of course is very inefficient coding. I was wondering what approach I should really be taking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted a way without factorizing the numbers, but found none. So:

```
list = {6, 7, 8, 9};
Max /@ FactorInteger[list][[All, All, 2]]

(*
{1,1,3,2}
*)
```

Let's check the timings in my old laptop:

```
list = RandomInteger[10^6, 10^6];
Max /@ FactorInteger[list][[All, All, 2]] // Timing // First
(*
  7 secs
*)
```

Comment: @ belisarius, this solution seems most straightforward to me  - many thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica essentially has `FreeQ2` built in:

```
FreeQ2[n_Integer] := MoebiusMu[n] != 0
```

Here's an idea for the rest. This depends on factoring an integer, but maybe something like

```
FreeQPow[n_, e_] := Head[n^(1/e)] === Power
```

Comment: Mathematica already has a built-in  `SquareFreeQ[n]`

Comment: @ RiemannZeta, thanks for your help on this - the bottom power solution is a nice start for me :)

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
pwrs = Flatten[Max /@ DeleteDuplicates@Last@Transpose@FactorInteger[#] & /@ list,1];
Transpose[{list,pwrs}]
```

Comment: Great - thanks for your help on this - I was trying to work out how to stack the `transpose` commands :)